# Toggling visibility between child elements while maintaining position

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to toggle visibility between a changing number of inline child elements as shown below. However as you can see they jump about because they are inline (which they need to be for semantic & responsive reasons) and therefore cannot set an absolute position. I am using a php cms for the data (kirby) so I can't fetch the strings as valuables directly, so my thinking is the only solution is to completely fade one element before the other appears.

Unless someone has another idea, what is the best way to do that using the code below? I can't crack it. Thanks!

```js
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.greetingWrapper span:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function(){
      $('.greetingWrapper :first-child').fadeOut()
        .next('span').fadeIn()
        .end().appendTo('.greetingWrapper');}, 
      3000);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>
<span class="greetingWrapper">
  <span>Hello</span>
  <span>Bonjour</span>
  <span>G'day</span>
  <span>Yeoboseyo</span>
</span>
- thanks for joining us.
</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

does the environment allow using `position: absolute;` on the spans?

```
<div>
  aaaaaa<span>123</span>345<span></span>abce
</div>

span {
  position: absolute;
}
```

makes the 123 and the 345 overlap